# How to fit a separate table in data warehouse model?

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, sql-data-warehouse, star-schema-datawarehouse

I have a table named AWARENESS_MEETINGS with name and date of the meeting as an attributes, it's not related to any other table in the database.
I am designing a data warehouse model, I can't fit it into the model its only related to the date dimension, and I can't determine if it's a fact or dimension table, the only business question related to the table is the count of the AWARENESS_MEETINGS by time.

EDITE:
[image]

EDITE 2:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a business requirement to count the number of awareness meetings then you would need:

- a fact table to hold the counts
- a meetings dimension to hold the meeting name
- a date dimension
- any other dimensions needed to slice/dice/aggregate the fact table

Comment: so I need to add a fact table only for one business requirement "count the number of awareness meetings",

Comment: what if other similar business requirement appears, wouldn't that result in a lot of fact tables without a connection between them, is it normal. please check the picture above, no other dimensions.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “fact tables without a connection between them” - why do you think there should be connections between fact tables? If you want to query a measure then that measure needs to be in a fact table - which may. result in a lot of fact tables

Comment: Sorry for the incomprehensible sentence I know there is no connection between the fact tables, I mean the model will be disjointed blocks, each business requirement will have a fact table with one dimension table plus the date. is it logical as a data warehouse model? please check the UPDATED picture above

Comment: The reason it looks odd is because your Dims aren’t correct e.g. Department is repeated multiple times so you probably need a Department Dim; Meeting and Awareness Meeting look like the same thing so should be a single Dim (possibly with a type attribute); there are probably a number of other issues you need to address

Comment: I worked with your advice and I did some changes, please take a look at the picture above for the final Model if you have any suggestions I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi - I'm happy to help with any specific questions you have but I'm afraid you're on your own as far as design reviews go